# Integral of a radial symmetric function.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I've found an article that essentially states that an integral of the form

$$
I[f] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(x_1,\ldots,x_N) dx_1 \ldots dx_N = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(r) dx_1 \ldots dx_N 
$$

where $r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots x_N^2}$, can **always** be split as product of two integrals, where the first integral is the surface of the $n$ dimensional sphere, say $A_n$ and the second integral is the radial integral

$$
R[f] = \int_0^1 f(r) r^{N-1}dr
$$

The article I've found only states the result, but it doesn't actually prove it, but assuming this results holds it proves that

$$
A_N = \frac{2 \pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma\left( \frac{N}{2}\right)}
$$

Is there a way to prove the statement which doesn't rely on generalized polar coordinates, which are a bit hard to remember and manipulate, if there's no other way is there an easy way to derive to generalized polar coordinates and again derive the result?

I would assume the proof is a calculus fact.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is radially symmetric, $f(\vec{x})d^N\vec{x}=r^{N-1}f(r)drd\Omega$, with $d\Omega$ an $(N-1)$-dimensional infinitesimal element over the angle coordinate(s). We don't need to work out how $d\Omega$ looks at all, so don't get out your $\sin\theta$s here. The claimed factorisation is immediate.

If you prefer a different proof that an $(N-1)$-sphere of radius $R$ has measure $\frac{2\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma(N/2)}R^{N-1}$, let's prove instead that an $N$-ball of radius $R$ has volume $\int_0^R\frac{2\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma(N/2)}r^{N-1}dr=\frac{\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma(N/2+1)}R^N$. (To clarify, an $n$-ball is $n$-dimensional, but an $n$-sphere is the $n$-dimensional surface of an $(n+1)$-ball.) Equivalently, the unit $N$-ball has measure $V_N:=\frac{\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma(N/2+1)}$. We'll proceed by induction.

The result is correct for $N=0$; a "$0$-sphere" is the single point in $0$-dimensional space, and the definition of measure is counting that point. (If that argument seems to strange, take $N=1$ as your base step, for which measure is a line segment's width, or failing that $N=2$, for which you just want a circle's area.) By slicing an $N$-ball into  hypercylinders of infinitesimal thickness with $(N-1)$-ball cross sections of radius $\sqrt{1-x^2}$,$$V_N=\int_{-1}^1V_{N-1}(1-x^2)^{(N-1)/2}dx=2V_{N-1}\int_0^1(1-x^2)^{(N-1)/2}dx\\=V_{N-1}\int_0^1y^{-1/2}(1-y)^{(N-1)/2}dx=V_{N-1}\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,\,\frac{N+1}{2}\right).$$(The intuition of this is easiest with slicing a sphere into cylinders, since you can visualise that.) So the inductive step is$$V_{N-1}=\frac{\pi^{(N-1)/2}}{\Gamma((N+1)/2)}\implies V_N=\frac{\pi^{(N-1)/2}}{\Gamma((N+1)/2)}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma((N+1)/2)}{\Gamma(N/2)+1},$$which is what we needed.

Comment: How did you get your very first equality?

Comment: @user8469759 Well, that's just the polar form of $d^N\vec{x}$. It needs to be proportional to $d(r^N)$, because an $N$-ball of radius $R$ wouldn't otherwise have measure $\propto R^N$.

Comment: So you implicity applied a coordinate transformation am I right?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, like when you write $f(x)dx=f(x)g^\prime(u)du$ if $x=g(u)$.

Comment: Ok, but to prove that equality you want to know the coordinate transformation. Or proving the existance maybe. I wanted to avoid an explicit computation if possible.

Comment: @user8469759 But calculating $A_N$ is all you need, which is what the rest of my answer did.

Comment: I'm not sure I've explained my problem correctly. The statement I struggle to understand rigorously is why we can split the integral in a radial part and a non radial part. I can understand intuitively, but not formally (without passing through the polar coordinates).

Comment: @user8469759 Fair enough. I deliberately avoided deriving the transformation in its gory details because all that matters is factorizability. All I'll say to conclude is that essentially the reason it happens is because when the problem only depends on one variable in the revised coordinate system you get separability; it's not the fact we're working with polar coordinates in particular that gets the credit for that.

Comment: Could you instead go through those details since it is not dependent from the polar coordinates? That is my actual question at the end of the day.